# conntrack dump stack when running with high rate traffic related to checksum failure

Tags: crash, checksum, coredump, netfilter

I'm running the conntrack over OVS on Fedora 24, with 4.11.12 kernel, on server with Xeon cpu with 20 physical cores + 20 virtual cores.

trying to check limits of conntrack performance by sending traffic from traffic generator (cisco Trex) to my fedora server through Mellanox ConnectX 5 NIC 40G on the DUT.

with sample pcap of tcp youtube.

I see that the usage of one core suddenly reach 100% while all the other between 30%-60%, then drops occured, and I see the below stack on dmesg output,
it is relevant to checksum failure..
can any one help with the debug and why conntrack crash?

```
net_ratelimit: 80 callbacks suppressed
[1890729.033836] ens1f0: hw csum failure
[1890729.038722] CPU: 24 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/24 Tainted: G           OE   4.11.12-100.fc24.x86_64 #1
[1890729.049508] Hardware name: HP ProLiant DL380 Gen9/ProLiant DL380 Gen9, BIOS P89 07/18/2016

[1890729.059798] Call Trace:
[1890729.063226]  <IRQ>
[1890729.066369]  dump_stack+0x63/0x86
[1890729.070720]  netdev_rx_csum_fault+0x38/0x40
[1890729.076119]  __skb_checksum_complete+0xb3/0xc0
[1890729.079215] ens1f0: hw csum failure
[1890729.086839]  nf_ip_checksum+0xc3/0xf0
[1890729.091590]  tcp_error+0xed/0x210 [nf_conntrack]
[1890729.097607]  nf_conntrack_in+0xd3/0x4f0 [nf_conntrack]
[1890729.104274]  ? dev_queue_xmit+0x10/0x20
[1890729.108383] ens1f0: hw csum failure
[1890729.114346]  ? ovs_vport_send+0xcf/0x180 [openvswitch]
[1890729.120899]  __ovs_ct_lookup+0xa3/0xd80 [openvswitch]
[1890729.127284]  ? find_bucket.isra.2+0x58/0x60 [openvswitch]
[1890729.134012]  ? nf_ct_get_tuple+0x78/0x90 [nf_conntrack]
[1890729.140719]  ? nf_ct_get_tuplepr+0xb2/0xc0 [nf_conntrack]
[1890729.147976]  ovs_ct_execute+0x3ec/0x620 [openvswitch]
[1890729.154273]  ? ovs_ct_execute+0x3ec/0x620 [openvswitch]
[1890729.161248]  do_execute_actions+0x8d/0x1680 [openvswitch]
[1890729.168224]  ? do_execute_actions+0x8d/0x1680 [openvswitch]
[1890729.175058]  ovs_execute_actions+0x43/0x120 [openvswitch]
[1890729.182034]  ? ovs_execute_actions+0x43/0x120 [openvswitch]
[1890729.188920]  ovs_dp_process_packet+0x84/0x130 [openvswitch]
[1890729.189382] ens1f0: hw csum failure
[1890729.200644]  ? ovs_ct_update_key+0x94/0xe0 [openvswitch]
[1890729.207459]  ? ovs_ct_update_key+0x94/0xe0 [openvswitch]
[1890729.214109]  ovs_vport_receive+0x76/0xd0 [openvswitch]
[1890729.220567]  ? mlx5_eq_int+0x49c/0x4b0 [mlx5_core]
[1890729.226903]  ? mlx5e_completion_event+0x36/0x40 [mlx5_core]
[1890729.233851]  ? mlx5_cq_completion+0x54/0xb0 [mlx5_core]
[1890729.240251]  ? mlx5_eq_int+0x49c/0x4b0 [mlx5_core]
[1890729.241999] ens1f0: hw csum failure
[1890729.251399]  ? csum_partial_ext+0x9/0x10
[1890729.256754]  ? __skb_checksum+0x12f/0x2b0
[1890729.261867]  ? ___slab_alloc+0x2ac/0x570
[1890729.267119]  ? sched_clock+0x9/0x10
[1890729.271799]  netdev_frame_hook+0xdf/0x170 [openvswitch]
[1890729.278434]  __netif_receive_skb_core+0x319/0xa30
[1890729.284747]  ? tcp4_gro_receive+0x11c/0x1c0
[1890729.290111]  __netif_receive_skb+0x18/0x60
[1890729.295468]  netif_receive_skb_internal+0x40/0xb0
[1890729.301506]  napi_gro_receive+0xc2/0xe0
[1890729.306772]  mlx5e_handle_rx_cqe_mpwrq+0x4b2/0x6c0 [mlx5_core]
[1890729.314109]  mlx5e_poll_rx_cq+0x83/0x830 [mlx5_core]
[1890729.320410]  mlx5e_napi_poll+0x8f/0x470 [mlx5_core]
[1890729.326747]  net_rx_action+0x25e/0x400
[1890729.331851]  __do_softirq+0x10c/0x2c5
[1890729.336844]  irq_exit+0xff/0x110
[1890729.341237]  do_IRQ+0x4f/0xd0
[1890729.345376]  common_interrupt+0x93/0x93
```